# How to find the record in a table that contains the maximum value?

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by, max, groupwise-maximum

Although this question looks simple, it is kind of tricky.

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id INT,
  value FLOAT,
  "date" DATETIME,
  group VARCHAR(50) 
);
```

I would like to obtain the `ID` and `value` of the records that contain the maximum `date` grouped by the column `group`. In other words, something like *"what is the newest value for each group?"* What query will answer that question?

I can get each group and its maximum date:

```
SELECT group, MAX(date) 
  FROM A 
  GROUP BY group; -- I also need the "ID" and "value"`
```

But I would like to have the "ID" and value of the record with the highest date.

Making a `JOIN` between `A` and the result could be the answer, but there is no way of knowing which record `MAX(date)` refers to (in case the `date` repeats).

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO A
  VALUES
(1, 1.0, '2000-01-01', 'A'),
(2, 2.0, '2000-01-02', 'A'),
(3, 3.0, '2000-01-01', 'B'),
(4, 2.0, '2000-01-02', 'B'),
(5, 1.0, '2000-01-02', 'B')
;
```

Comment: Duplicate of "[SQL query for finding representative rows in a table](//stackoverflow.com/q/375262/90527)", especially given that neither state how multiple max rows should be handled. Which should be closed as duplicate is a toss-up, given each has answers with unique approaches. Possibly a duplicate of "[How do I select only the latest entry in a table for each group when each latest is a single row?](//stackoverflow.com/q/374846/90527)".

Answer (score 8):

You could try with a subquery

```
select group, id, value, date from A where date in
( select MAX(date) as date
  from A
  group by group )
order by group
```

Answer (score 4):

This is just what analytic functions were made for:

```
select group,
       id,
       value
from   (
       select group,
              id,
              value,
              date,
              max(date) over (partition by group) max_date_by_group
       from A
       )
where  date = max_date_by_group
```

Answer (score 2):

If date is unique, then you already have your answer. If date is not unique, then you need some other uniqueifier. Absent a natural key, your ID is as good as any. Just put a MAX (or MIN, whichever you prefer) on it:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN (
    --Dedupe any non unqiue dates by getting the max id for each group that has the max date
    SELECT Group, MAX(Id) as Id
    FROM A 
    JOIN (
        --Get max date for each group
        SELECT group, MAX(date) as Date 
        FROM A 
        GROUP BY group
    ) as MaxDate ON
        A.Group = MaxDate.Group
        AND A.Date = MaxDate.Date
    GROUP BY Group
) as MaxId ON
    A.Group = MaxId.Group
    AND A.Id= MaxId.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Date column is unique for each group I think something like this might work:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Value
FROM A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Group, MAX(Date) As MaxDate FROM A GROUP BY Group) B
    ON A.Group = B.Group AND A.Date = B.MaxDate
```

Comment: That makes it kind of hard to find a single most recent record for each group :]