# Find max value and show corresponding value from different field in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, max

I have a table with data about cities that includes their name, population and other fields irrelevant to my question.

```
ID      Name    Population
1       A       45667   
2       B       123456  
3       C       3005    
4       D       13769
```

To find the max population is basic, but I need a resulting table that has the max population in one column, and the corresponding city's name in another column

```
Population      Name    
123456          B
```

I've looked through [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376518/how-to-get-the-record-of-a-table-who-contains-the-maximum-value) questions, but for some reason the answers look over-complicated. Is there a way to write the query in 1 or 2 lines?

Comment: You could have more than one city with a given (max) population.  Is it acceptable a multiple-record result for you?

Comment: the table is real world data of US cities, so there are no duplicates.

Comment: I think you don't know the Murphy's law :-)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are several ways that this can be done:

A filter in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select id, name, population
from yourtable
where population in (select max(population)
                     from yourtable)
```

Or a subquery:

```
select id, name, population
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(population) MaxPop
  from yourtable
) t2
  on t1.population = t2.maxpop;
```

Or you can use `TOP WITH TIES`. If there can be no ties, then you can remove the `with ties`. This will include any rows that have the same population value:

```
select top 1 with ties id, name, population
from yourtable
order by population desc
```

Since you are using SQL Server you can also use ranking functions to get the result:

```
select id, name, population
from
(
  select id, name, population,
    row_number() over(order by population desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92998/9) of all.

As a side note on the ranking function, you might want to use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`. Then in the event you have more than one city with the same population you will get both city names. (See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9df7/4))

Comment: @HDunn You are welcome, I wanted to show you several working versions. :)

Comment: "order by .... desc limit 1" is a simple and nice idea, that does not strike to mind sometime :)