# Find max value and show corresponding value from different field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, max, greatest-n-per-group, corresponding-records

So I found this similar question and answer at ([Find max value and show corresponding value from different field in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946089/find-max-value-and-show-corresponding-value-from-different-field-in-sql-server)) but I want to take it one step further.  I want to get the latest date for each ID and the corresponding TYPE instead of just the absolute max for all entries.  Any suggestions?

```
ID      Type        Date
1       Initial      1/5/15 
1       Periodic     3/5/15
2       Initial      2/5/15  
3       Initial      1/10/15
3       Periodic     3/6/15  
4       Initial      3/8/15
```

The code below shows how to get just the max date of ALL entries, but I want the max date for each ID and then the corresponding Type.

```
select id, type, date
from yourtable
where date in (select max(date)
                     from yourtable)
```

OR

```
select id, type, date
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(date) maxdate
  from yourtable
) t2
  on t1.date = t2.maxdate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first method with a correlated subquery:

```
select id, type, date
from yourtable as t
where date in (select max(date)
               from yourtable as t2
               where t2.id = t.id);
```

Or, group by `id` in the second:

```
select t1.id, t1.type, t1.date
from yourtable as t1 inner join
     (select id, max(date) maxdate
      from yourtable
      group by id
     ) t2
     on t1.date = t2.maxdate and t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  That makes sense and I believe you have fixed my issue!