# Find certain values and show corresponding value from different field in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I found these 2 articles but they don't quite answer my question...

[Find max value and show corresponding value from different field in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946089/find-max-value-and-show-corresponding-value-from-different-field-in-sql-server)

[Find max value and show corresponding value from different field in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203334/find-max-value-and-show-corresponding-value-from-different-field-in-ms-access)

I have a table like this...

```
ID      Type        Date
1       Initial      1/5/15 
1       Periodic     3/5/15
2       Initial      2/5/15  
3       Initial      1/10/15
3       Periodic     3/6/15  
4        
5       Initial      3/8/15
```

I need to get all of the ID numbers that are "Periodic" or NULL and corresponding date.  So I want a to get query results that looks like this...

```
ID     Type    Date
1    Periodic  3/5/15
3    Periodic  3/6/15
4
```

I've tried

```
select id, type, date1
from Table1 as t
where type in (select type
               from Table1 as t2
               where ((t2.type) Is Null) or "" or ("periodic"));
```

But this doesn't work...  From what I've read about NULL you can't compare null values...
[Why in SQL NULL can't match with NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853944/why-in-sql-null-cant-match-with-null)

So I tried

```
SELECT id, type, date1
FROM Table1 AS t
WHERE type in (select type
               from Table1 as t2
               where ((t.Type)<>"Initial"));
```

But this doesn't give me the ID of 4...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Based on your user name, I'm guessing that the correct tag is ms-access.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you just want:

```
select id, type, date1
from Table1 as t
where (t.type Is Null) or (t.type = "") or (t.type = "periodic");
```

The `or` applies to boolean expressions, not to values being compared.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Ya, but then if I add to the original set of data "4   Periodic 3/6/15", I get both "4 Periodic 3/6/15" and "4"...  So if there are both, I need to just get the "4 Periodic 3/6/15"...  That's why I was trying to match them...