# Find MAX from field1, corresponding field2, GROUP BY field3

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data like:

```
id, id2, datetime_created
1, 1, 9/10
1, 2, 9/9
1, 3, 9/8
2, 4, 9/8
2, 5, 9/2
2, 6, 9/1
3, 7, 9/3
3, 8, 9/4
3, 9, 9/5
```

Expected output:

```
id, id2
1, 1
2, 4
3, 9
```

I've tried a number of things, including:

```
SELECT id, id2, MAX(datetime_created)
FROM table
GROUP BY id2
```

,

```
SELECT id, id2, MAX(datetime_created)
FROM table
GROUP BY id, id2
```

,

```
SELECT id, id2
FROM table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(datetime_created), id
    FROM table)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946089/find-max-value-and-show-corresponding-value-from-different-field-in-sql-server) question was not sufficient. The kicker is the `GROUP BY` a different field than one of the ones I need without `GROUP BY`ing the second field, as this returns too many rows (from my sample dataset, it would return all rows).

Comment: In the expected result, there is no mention of datetime_created. Do you really mean "GROUP BY field3" and not "ignore field 3", that has no bearing on the result as far as the sample data is concerned?

Comment: I don't need the `datetime_created`, but I need the `id` and `id2` `GROUP BY id` with the most recent `datetime_created` for that `id`.  Several of the answers I've received understood the question.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I misread. No need to suggest I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number() over()` instead of `group by`:

```
SELECT
    id, id2, datetime_created
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, id2, datetime_created
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime_created DESC) AS rn
    FROM table1
) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will give you access to the whole rows that have the maximum datetime value

Reference: *[ROW_NUMBER Window Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html)*

Comment: @ChootsMagoots using UPPERCASE for SQL is a preference, not a requirement

Comment: Yeah, but my boss and my coworker both don't use uppercase, and I find it MUCH easier to read... I don't feel comfortable asking them to change how they do things, but I do feel comfortable requesting it here, particularly because I can do the work.  Small victories :P

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following one:

```
SELECT id, id2
  FROM table
 WHERE (id, datetime_created) in
      (
        SELECT id, MAX(datetime_created)
          FROM table
         GROUP BY id
       )
ORDER BY id;
```

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XOJNCO67916) *[P.S. even if in Oracle the same logic works]*

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:

```
SELECT tt.id,tt.id2 FROM table tt LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(datetime_created) AS cr
          FROM table 
         GROUP BY id)q ON q.id=tt.id AND q.cr=tt.datetime_created WHERE q.id IS NOT NULL;
```